# Import Python function at top or call them in code

Tags: python, architecture

Is it better / more pythonic to import functions at the top of the file like so:

```
from file import f1, f2
```

and call as

```
def do_something():
   f1()
   etc....
```

or just import the package and call them when necessary

```
import file
...
def do_something():
   file.f1()
   etc....
```

Comment: Is the question A) whether to put `import` on top or in the function, or B) whether to `from file import f1` or `import file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` statements themselves should be at the top of the file (of course), but whether you use `import somemodule` or `from somemodule import f1, f2` is up to you. The second form involves less typing, but the first form makes the code more readable, since it make it explicit where imported names are coming from, and I guess that makes it more Pythonic, especially when you're importing a lot of names from a variety of different modules.

A good compromise is the `import somemodule as` variant, eg

```
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
```

That adds minimal impact on the length of import names but still makes it clear where each imported name is coming from.

Having said all that, I have no problem with code that does `from somemodule import f1, f2` when `somemodule` is a well-known standard module like `itertools` or `random`, since readers of your code *should* be familiar with those names. But I'd be less pleased to see that form used for more obscure modules.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

So your first example is better and more "pythonic".

Comment: I think OP is asking whether to use the given import, or just **import file**.  The question isn't written quite clearly enough.

Comment: @Prune, good point, I couldn't find anything in the documentation that gets that specific for function imports, but when in doubt this PEP-8 seems the closest that covers all these situations. Personal preference, as in PM 2Ring's answer, seems to be the best alternative.